# Variable not stored in array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, store

I have the following which checks a list of keywords against urls:

```
function searchUrls()
{
    $result = array();

    $urlList = file("link_to.txt");
    $keywordList = explode("\n", file_get_contents("link_to.txt"));

    for($index = 0; $index <count($urlList); $index++)  
    {  
        $urlList[$index] = str_replace("\n", "", $urlList[$index]);  
        $data = file_get_contents("$urlList[$index]"); 

        $keywords = array();
        foreach($keywordList as $keyword)
        {  
            if (stripos($data, $keyword) !== false) 
            {
                $keywords[] = $Keyword.'found';
            } 
        }
        $result[] = array('url' => $urlList[$index], 'status' => $keywords);
    }  
return $result;
}
```

when echo-ing out
`foreach($result['status'] as $keyword)`

only the 'found'is printing.

on
`var_dump($results)`
the variable isn't stored in the array but the text is?

How can this work to echo out the variable as well as the text?

Many thanks

Comment: Should be `$keywords[$key] = $keyword.'found';` instead of `$keywords[$key] = $Keyword.'found';` right ??

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran this the answer, not a comment.

Comment: sorry I dont see the difference between the two?

Comment: `$Keyword` doesn't exist. It should be `$keyword`

Comment: oh my god, 'hangs head in shame'. Thank you very much :)